# Laravel: Auth::user() returns null in custom console command

Tags: laravel, notifications

I want to send Notifications in laravel and I have a problem .I googled for the answer but I didn't found anything .My code it's looking like that:

```
    <?php
            
            namespace App\Notifications;
            
            use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
            use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
            use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
            use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
            use App\Models\Attribute;
            
            class ExpiredDateNotification extends Notification
            {
                use Queueable;
            
                public $attribute;
                /**
                 * Create a new notification instance.
                 *
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct($attribute)
                {
                    $this->attribute = $attribute;
                }
            
                /**
                 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
                 *
                 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
                 * @return array
                 */
                public function via($notifiable)
                {
                    return ['mail', 'database'];
                }
            
                /**
                 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
                 *
                 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
                 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
                 */
                public function toMail($notifiable)
                {
                    return (new MailMessage)
                                ->line('You must to renew your contract!')
                                ->line('Thank you for using our services!');
                }
            
                /**
                 * Get the array representation of the notification.
                 *
                 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
                 * @return array
                 */
                public function toArray($notifiable)
                {
                    return [
                      'name' => $this->attribute->attribute_name,
                      'expired_at' => $this->attribute->expired_at
                    ];
                }
            }
        
        
            <?php
        
        namespace App\Console;
        
        use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
        use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
        use App\Models\User;
        use App\Notifications\ExpiredDateNotification;
        use App\Models\Attribute;
        use App\Console\Commands\SendNotification;
        
        class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
        {
            /**
             * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
             *
             * @var array
             */
            protected $commands = [
                SendNotification::class
            ];
        
            /**
             * Define the application's command schedule.
             *
             * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
             * @return void
             */
            protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
            {
                $schedule->command('command:SendNotification');
            }
        
            /**
             * Register the commands for the application.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            protected function commands()
            {
                $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
        
                require base_path('routes/console.php');
            }
        }
    
    
    
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Console\Commands;
    
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    use App\Models\User;
    use App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use App\Notifications\ExpiredDateNotification;
    use DB;
    use Notification;
    
        class SendNotification extends Command
        {
            /**
             * The name and signature of the console command.
             *
             * @var string
             */
            protected $signature = 'command:SendNotification';
        
            /**
             * The console command description.
             *
             * @var string
             */
            protected $description = 'Send notification on email when an attribute is set to expire';
        
            /**
             * Create a new command instance.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            }
        
            /**
             * Execute the console command.
             *
             * @return int
             */
        

public function handle()
        {
            $users = auth()->user();;
            
                $attributes[] = User::join('object_models', 'object_models.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->
            join('attributes', 'attributes.object_id', '=', 'object_models.id')->
            where('attributes.expired_at', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(7))->
            where('users.id', '=', $user->id)->
            get();
       
 
          
                    $user->notify(new ExpiredDateNotification($attribute));
            
        }
    }
```

But here in handle function my $user = auth()->user() is NULL...and I can't send notifications..I googled for the solution in the last hours but I don't know how to resolve it..If you have a hint please tell me. Thank you

Comment: Send the user identifier to the command. The console does not know what user caused the command to happen

Comment: there isn't going to be an authenticated user from the console (there is no request being sent with a cookie or some key) ... how do you know what user the command should be sending to?

Comment: @apokryfos can you tell me how to do that? thank you

Comment: @lagbox yes you're right, but I don't know another method

Comment: if you are trying to get all users matching that criteria you can remove the `where` on `users.id`

Comment: You are using the scheduler to send notifications so you can either (1) not use the scheduler and instead the [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) and pass the identifier in the event constructor to use it when processing the event (2) put the identifier in a table and when the command runs on the schedule read the identifiers from that table and then clear the table

Comment: @lagbox I'm am trying to get just for the authenticated user...and to send the notifications for those attributes to that user..

Comment: @apokryfos, I'm new to laravel, and what you're saying it's difficult for me..I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Unless you fired your notification workflow from any part of a request's lifecycle (for example, after the user logs in), the `auth` helper has nowhere to pull the authenticated user from.

For the use case you're showing you'd have to provide it yourself, for example as a command argument:

```
protected $signature = 'command:SendNotification
                        {user_id : id of the recipient model}';

public function handle()
{
    $user_id = $this->argument('user_id');
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    // other commands

}
```

So executing `php artisan command:SendNotification 1` would act as if user 1 was authenticated.

The logic to figure out the expired attributes, if any, seems out of the scope of this question, so I'd suggest you start by checking it works using a dummy attribute;

```
 public function handle()
    {
        $user_id = $this->argument('user_id');
        $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
        $attribute = (object) [
                 'name'=>'dummyAttribute', 
                 'expired_at'=>now()->->addDays(7)
        ];
        $user->notify(new ExpiredDateNotification($attribute));

    }
```